# In Laravel Controller ,getting Error-Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts::DataTables() Is Undefined

Tags: php, laravel, charts, datatable

Hi I am new to Laravel and Datables. In my application I need to create Charts. For That I have followed the steps suggested at http://kevinkhill.github.io/LavaCharts/ but I am getting error "Khill\Lavacharts\Lavacharts::DataTables() Is Undefined" in the code -

```
$stocksTable = Lava::DataTables('Activitytaskprojects');
```

Please Suggest me which step I am missing. I think I am missing the datatable implementation. If it is then please suggest how to implement datatables.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest you to check the installation of that addition to Laravel.
  Second check again their [documentation](http://kevinkhill.github.io/LavaCharts/)  and [api](http://kevinkhill.github.io/LavaCharts/api.html). You probably missed something.

*Edit:*
Guess I missed it also. You wrote `Lava::DataTables();` instead of `Lava::DataTable();`
Try `$stocksTable = Lava::DataTable('Activitytaskprojects');`

Answer (score 0):

Read the [example](http://lavacharts.com/) and if you got error, try changing from this

```
  $stocksTable = Lava::DataTables('Activitytaskprojects');
```

to this

```
  $stocksTable = \Lava::DataTables('Activitytaskprojects');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Lavacharts (http://lavacharts.com) and also got same problem.

Assigning the alias is not optional in Laravel and it is not auto assigned. In terminal try following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
artisan config:clear
artisan clear-compiled
```